# Write an anonymous program that declares variables, calls the procedure and displays the input and output

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm having some trouble writing a procedure which displays the number of times a name occurs in a database when given an ID as input. For example if you type in 1 it will correspond with a last name that occurs twice in the database so it should print out a '2'. My question is i'm not sure how to display the number of times that the name occurs at the end. Bellow is the code I have so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ZRBIDInput (StudentID  IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
numberOfStudents   NUMBER;
var_lastname varchar2(10);
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;

SELECT Lastname INTO var_lastname    
FROM ZRB_STUDENT
WHERE ID = StudentID;

SELECT COUNT (*)
INTO numberOfStudents
FROM ZRB_STUDENT
WHERE Lastname =  var_lastname;

dbms_output.put_line('Num Of Students - '||numberOfStudents);

END ZRBIDInput;
/

BEGIN
ZRBIDInput('1');
ZRBIDInput('6');
ZRBIDInput('7');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your procedure in `Oracle` as below. This will take 1 as input and list down all the stuednts with the same last name as of student with `Id=1`;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ZRBIDInput (StudentID  IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
   numberOfStudents   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO numberOfStudents
     FROM ZRB_STUDENT
    WHERE Lastname =  (SELECT Lastname     
                       FROM ZRB_STUDENT
                       WHERE ID = StudentID );

   dbms_output.put_line('Num Of Students - '||numberOfStudents);


END ZRBIDInput;
```

Execution;

```
SQL> exec ZRBIDInput('1');
       2
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This is the code I have now that works.

i've updated the code above and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Q: "... how to display ... at the end."

To get the contents of the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer "displayed", the client will need to read from the buffer, and do the display.

If we're running from the SQL*Plus command line client, we can issue a

```
set serverout on
```

statement before we execute the anonymous block. To get this working, I'd whittle it down to something real simple, before mucking it up with a call to a stored procedure.

```
SQL> set serverout on

SQL> begin dbms_output.put_line('Hello World!); end;
   > /
```

Make sure that's working like we expect. Then we can move on to getting something more useful displayed, calling a stored procedure, whatever.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG099

NOTE:  This applies to the SQL*Plus command line client. Other clients (e.g. T.O.A.D) have other mechanisms for displaying the contents of the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood exactly but I edited my code accordingly.

Comment: The `put_line` procedure puts a line into the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer. There's corresponding `get_lines` procedure to retrieve data from the buffer.  So, the client program will need to execute call to the `dbms_output.get_lines` procedure, and then take the output and display it. And that functionality is builtin to the SQL\*Plus client, and can be enabled with the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` command. NOTE: that's a SQL\*Plus command that affects the behavior of the client; that 's *not* a SQL statement. (This answer only addresses the question about getting the `dbms_output.put_line` "displayed".)